Construction of the unit disc on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by using union of a collection of closed boxes.
(I know that the statement is proved on the forum but the construction of it is not discussed.)
I tried something like this;
First define $A:=\partial$$(B(\frac{1}{2},0))$ then observe the union of the collection:

$\bigcup_{x\in A} R(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},x)$

Then the union sums up to;

$\bigcup_{x\in A} R(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},x)$=$B(1,0)$

But i also know that boxes from collection are all open so it does not solve our problem.
My question is:
(i) Is there a proper construction of closed boxes that their union sums up to our open disc?(uncountable or countable)
(ii) If there is not that we can construct how can we prove it?

Too unclear. You should define every object, at the very least. What is $R$? Most importantly, what are you trying to do?

R is a box on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (for some r>0 and $(x_1,x_2)$$\in\mathbb{R}^2$ $R(r,x)={(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \vert a-x_1  \vert<r,  \vert b-x_2 \vert <r }$)and I try to get some collection of closed boxes so that the union of them is the unit disc on $\mathbb{R}^2$. And I didn't understand that why is it unclear that what I am trying to do. I literally explained it in the caption of the question.

Draw a picture to convince yourself that every point in the open disk is in some closed box inside the disk. If you must, write down just what such a box might be in terms of the coordinates of the point.

Yeah something like this will work. But If the union doesn’t have to be countable or have any restriction then it’s very easy though. The set is open so each point is in a ball. Now just put a box inside each such ball.

The following is a construction I have seen in a measure theory course:
First, divide $\mathbb R^2$ into unit squares (imagine a square tiling). Pick all the closed squares contained in the disk. Next, for all the squares that overlap with the disk but aren’t contained in it, divide each into four smaller squares with half the side lengths. Pick all the smaller squares contained within the disk. Repeat this procedure to end up with a countable collection of closed boxes whose union is the open disk.

Yes, this idea is correct. However this proof is rather vague. You should prove that the disk is exhausted by this process.

@GiuseppeNegro I agree. I’ll add a proof when I find some time.

I first defined $S_q(r,x)=${$a\in\mathbb{R}^n$: $\vert x_i-a_i \vert \leq r$ $\forall i\in \{1,...,n \}$} Then define

I added the closed square with r=0 and x=(0,0) to include (0,0) into the union

$A_i=S_q(0,0)\cup S_q(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{i},x)$ where $x\in X$ and defined
$X:=\partial (B(\frac{1}{2},0))$  then the union sums up to a box
$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$=$R(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},x)\cup\{(0,0)\}$
After that i take the uncountable union as ;
$\bigcup_{x\in X}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)$=$B(1,0)$
Is this sums up to the unit disc, or did I used fully closed squares if I did something wrong correct me
